# How can if statements be executed after an else statement has met its requirements?

Tags: java, if-statement

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    int hankees, socks;

    out.print("Hankees and Socks scores?  ");
    hankees = keyboard.nextInt();
    socks = keyboard.nextInt();
    out.println();

    if (hankees > socks) {
        out.println("Hankees win...");
        out.print("Hankees: ");
        out.println(hankees);
        out.print("Socks:   ");
        out.println(socks);
    } else {
        out.println("It's a tie...");
        out.print("Hankees: ");
        out.println(hankees);
        out.print("Socks:   ");
        out.println(socks);
    }
    if (socks > hankees) {
        out.println("Socks win...");
        out.print("Socks:   ");
        out.println(socks);
        out.print("Hankees: ");
        out.println(hankees);
    } 

    keyboard.close();
}
```

}

I am very new to Java, but I have noticed that Java codes tend to be executed regardless of the codes that follow if the conditions are met.
So here I expected the else code to be executed ( in the case of socks> hankees)
but the if statement that follows is properly taken into account.
I would very much appreciate it if someone could explain why.

EDIT:
This is a code from a book and it is originally formatted as how everyone is pointing out(if-> else if-> else ).

I was just changing a few things around and i ran into some confusing results.
With the changed up code(first code posted) when I put in 10 for hankees and 90 for socks, the result i get is this.

Hankees and Socks scores?  10 90

Socks win...
Socks:   90
Hankees: 10

As if the else statement is not being executed(Which I do expect to be executed since the conditions are met before the last if statement)

My question is : why it is not being executed?

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. What are you expecting? and why? and what is actually happening that doesn't meet your expectations? and why not?

Comment: What does "properly taken into account" mean?  That's where I'm lost in your question.

Comment: Are you asking why that second if (socks> hankees) is being executed?

Comment: Hello guys, sorry about the confusion, I edited the original post. I hope that clears my question up.

Comment: It is the exact output. I have executed it once more just now to be sure.

Comment: Hard to believe. Impossible actually. This cannot possibly be the real code.

Answer (score 0):

There is a little mistake in your algorithm. Regardless the coding language you will use the if statement will be handled from top to bottom. Then, in case of (socks > hankees) the first else block code will be executed cause the first if condition is false. Then the second else will be true so the third block code will be executed too.

It is a good time to use the `else if` keyword.

```
if(hankees > socks){
    //hankees won
}
else if(hankees == socks){
    //it's a tie
}
else{
    //socks won
}
```

Comment: There is no '`else if` keyword'. There is an `if` keyword and an `else` keyword.

Comment: @EJP I was suggesting you to use this keyword ^^ https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Answer (score 0):

When I run this I get the result:

```
It's a tie...
Hankees: 10
Socks:   90
Socks win...
Socks:   90
Hankees: 10
```

So to answer your question, the else statement should and does run.  You must have a slightly different code than what you posted here if you aren't getting the "It's a tie..." part.

Comment: I found out what the problem was, I unchecking the save code box that pops up in Eclipse when I run the code. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Then your else statemnet should be the first statement then following the "if condition" or you can add a while loop.